# MissingPluginException after upgrading to Android embedding v2

Tags: flutter

I need to implement a plugin in my app. For this, I needed to migrate to Android embedding v2. Through the documentation, I tried upgrading. Below is the documentation I referred:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

For upgrading, I changed my imports in MainActivity.kt

to `import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity` and removed the onCreate Method as well.

In AndroidManifest.xml I added the below meta-data

```
   <meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
    android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
   />
  <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2"/>
  <meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
    android:value="true" />
```

After adding this I got some error so I changed the Application.java to this

```
 public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
      //GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));

  }
}
```

The application is installing but I am getting below errors after

```
 Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)



 MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app. Tried `flutter clean` and `flutter pub cache repair` as well but nothing works.

Comment: do you use path provider? it seems that your are calling `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` from another isolate, if you do please post the code

Comment: @Henok yes i am using path provider. but i am getting same errors for many plugins

Comment: Try adding `android:name=".Application"` in your manifests application tag

Comment: @Henok it is already present

Comment: what about MainActivity.java?

Comment: based on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46679 there is still an unfixed issue if you are using path_provider 1.5.1, so if your path_provider is the same version try upgrading to the latest version ( currently path_provider: ^1.6.14)

Comment: There is MainActivity.kt in the project. I also tried downgrading and upgrading the path provider plugin but it still does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221563/discussion-between-user9561-and-henok).

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the error, MissingPluginException, bon't forget this last [bit](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects#add-to-app-migration) in your AndroidManifest:

```
       </activity>
   </application>
   <meta-data
    android:name="flutterEmbedding"
    android:value="2" />
 </manifest>
```